# basic PHP SQL - query multiple stuff from URL

Tags: php, android, mysql

So, I wanted to use two params on the url to query  from my server but I'm not being able to do it.

The url is : localhost/database/getTable?sLang=English&sId=1

The php Script is:

```
<?php



if(isset($_REQUEST['sLang']))
if(isset($_REQUEST['sId'])) 
    {

    $con = mysql_connect("blabla","blablabla","blablabla");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
        if (!$con)
            {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        mysql_select_db("database", $con);

        $sLang = $_REQUEST['sLang']; //valor customer ID = valor requisitado
        SdID = $_REQUEST['sID']
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE language = '$sLang' AND id = '$sId" ) or die('Errant Query:'); //escolher da tabela comments onde valor da coluna id = Valor reuisitado

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
        $output[]=$row;
            }

        header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

        print(json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

        mysql_close($con);

        }
        else
        {
        $output = "not found";
        print(json_encode($output));
        }


?>
```

I'm just returning the sLang Values and the url changes to : localhost/database/getTable?sLang=English

How can I query the database using the two params sLang and sId?

Best regards

Comment: NEVER use `$_REQUEST` to pull data. You're leaving huge security holes open. In this case use `$_GET` instead.

Comment: Remove your single quote in $sId inside mysql_query

Comment: use $_GET to retrieve values passed via URL parameters. But make sure you escape/sanitize them! (Keywork: SQL Injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing `$` and missing semi-colon for `SdID = $_REQUEST['sID']`

Plus, `SdID` has a typo.

which should most likely read as

```
$sId = $_REQUEST['sID'];
```

which you're using in conjunction with `AND id = '$sId"`

Also `AND id = '$sId"` needs a quote `AND id = '$sId'"` or remove the erroneous quote.

`SdID` is presently being evaluated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Another thing I noticed is the word `table` in `("SELECT * FROM table WHERE`

***An insight:*** If that is the DB table's actual name, it needs to be wrapped in backticks:

```
("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ...
```

- `table` is a [**MySQL reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

---

Also, instead of:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sLang']))
if(isset($_REQUEST['sId']))
```

it's best to use

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sLang']) && isset($_REQUEST['sId']))

 {

 // code

 }
```

or

```
if(isset($_GET['sLang']) && isset($_GET['sId']))

 {

 // code

 }
```

---

Using [**error checking**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have and ***should have*** thrown you errors, as well as `mysql_error()` in your query, if that is your actual code that you have posted initially, should there be an edit made on your part afterwards.

---

- ***Sidenote:*** Do take the comments posted under your question seriously.

Answer (score 0):

1) Typo: SdID = $_REQUEST['sID'] (SdID should be $sID)

```
$sID = $_REQUEST['sID']
```

2) Coding Method: instead of nesting the if() statements like that, consider using

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sLang']) && isset($_REQUEST['sId']))
```

3) SQL Insertion Avoidance: When loading GET or POST values into a variable, you should strip out unnecessary characters or encode the string to avoid SQL Insertion Attacks:

```
$sLang = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $_REQUEST['sLang'])
```

This will strip out anything but a-Z and 0-9 so your code can't be used to violate the inevitable SQL query.